# Run method when JavaFX file load

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a Quiz Project.

Quiz Project on Github

https://github.com/coding-fellow/QuizMySQL

[image]

I have created a userdashboard.fxml file where the user can hit the "Take Quiz" button to enter a new Quiz.fxml file where the user can take the quiz.
but when the user enters Quiz.fxml file it did not show quiz so I have created a button "start" that calls ShowQuestion method to showqustions.

[image]

I want that when the user hit "Take Quiz" then Quiz.fxml file load and without hitting "start:" button it should show question.

[image]

here is the code of userdashboard class.

[image]

Comment: Since the quiz data is coming from the data access layer, not the layer the gui recides in, it would be preferable to wrap the data retrieved in an object and pass that object to the controller (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml). Alternatively there's the `initialize` method of the controller but that way the data access is not properly seperated from the gui...

Comment: Thanks alot bro❤